# Missing files when extending AndroidTestCase, TestCase working fine

Tags: java, android, junit, android-testing

I have an Android test project that writes several files into the sdcard with a hierarchy of:

```
appresults
 |
 +--- gen
 |
 +--- results
```

If I make my Test.java file extend `AndroidTestCase`, my test will run correctly but when I do `adb pull`, some of the files will be missing, namely, anything inside the results directory. Curiously, the files inside the gen directory will trickle in. That is to say I will do `adb pull` and get 4, run it again right away and get 8, and so on until they all appear.

If I make my Test.java file extend `TestCase` however, `adb pull` will find all the files no problem.

I overrode `tearDown()` to do nothing thinking `super.tearDown()` could have been the difference in the `AndroidTestCase` scenario but it did not help.

I added logs at the very end of my test method querying the file I am missing for name, size, and last modified and it returned appropriate values so as far as I know, up to the last second my test is running, that file is present.

I also noticed that `AndroidTestCase` does an additional `testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly` but [from what I can see](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/test/AndroidTestCase.java#AndroidTestCase), all this does is ensure the context is not null:

```
public void  [More ...] testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly() {
     assertNotNull("Context is null. setContext should be called before tests are run",
             mContext);
 }
```

So I guess my question is, does `AndroidTestCase` on `Android 4.0.3.` clean up files for you? If so, why does it clean up some files and not others?

---

Per request, below is code that shows what I am doing:

```
File myPath = new File("some path");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8");
out.append("abcde");
out.close();
if (myPath.exists()) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Name: " + myPath.getAbsoluteFilePath());
    Log.w(TAG, "Size: " + myPath.length());
}
```

The code would return two warnings like:

`Name: some path` and `Size: 5`

Showing that a) the file was created at the right place, and b) the size was correct, the write succeeded. But as soon as my test exited, bam, no `adb pull` output on that directory. (the results one)

Comment: You should provide some code to show what you are doing in your tests

Comment: @dtmilano Wasn't sure that it would help--added.

Comment: "some path" should be on the SD card

Comment: @dtmilano Correct. `"some path" =~ ^/sdcard/.*`, if you will :)

Comment: @dtmilano What I mean is, "some path" is in fact in the `/sdcard` directory. But as soon as it returns it is gone. It is worth repeating that if I extend `TestCase`, the file is there with no problems. This is no longer a problem blocking me, instead it is a question to gratify my own curiosity at this seemingly strange behavior.